# zsh in tmux watching for .config/.zshrc but ~/.zshrc allready exists

Tags: zsh, tmux, zshrc

It happened suddenly. I had try to move dotfiles to config, but i ditched this idea and all seems to be good until i started tmux

I tried to find env, which can cause it, but there isnt $Z* set and tmux.conf dont contain any suspicious

Images:

[.zshrc exists in ~](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0E7L.png)

[tmux trying to find .config/.zshrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncjik.png)

[tmux.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmxSP.png)

Comment: I must admit that I have nearly no experience with tmux. However tmux certainly does not care how you have set up your zsh configuration. From the error message in your second screenshot you posted, I would conlcude that you set somewhere `ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config`, so I would first check whether this variable really has been set.